# Gridview images mixed up on scroll

Tags: android, gridview

I'm trying to solve this issue about mixed up images in gridview when scrolling. I already saw similar posts here about this issue but unfortunately I didn't solve it yet.

I use asynctask to load the images in the gridView, and **I have only imageView** in the grid.

**Thanks!**

Here is my code:

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

         ImageView img;
        if (convertView == null) {
            img = new ImageView(GalleryActivity.this);
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) GalleryActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            int width = size.x;
            width = width / 3 - 4;
            img.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(width, width));
            img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        } else {
            img = (ImageView) convertView;
        }


        File dics = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
        File dir = new File(dics, "yyy");

        if (!dir.exists() && !dir.mkdirs()) {
            img.setImageResource(holder(position + 1));
        } else {
            String file_name = dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + (position + 1) + ".jpg";
            if (new File(file_name).exists()) {
                BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(img);
                task.execute(file_name);
                items[position].setStatus(1);
            } else {
                img.setImageResource(holder(position + 1));
            }
        }
        return img;
    }


class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
        private String data;

        public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
            imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
        }

        // Decode image in background.
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            data = params[0];
            return decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(data,100,100);

        }

        // Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
                final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
                if (imageView != null) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(String resId,
                                                         int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(resId,options);
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(resId);
    }

    public int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
```

Comment: Why not use one of the many [image-loading libraries for Android](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/46) that take care of all of this for you?

Comment: @CommonsWare it works perfect except this issue. Can you help with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind your problem is that the `BitmapWorkerTask` is not finished by starting order so it could override the newest result by older one.

To avoid this you have to keep one `BitmapWorkerTask` for each view and cancel the old one if it's still working so it doesn't override the result of the new `BitmapWorkerTask`

You can use `setTag` and `getTag` methods to achive this purpose and keep a reference of the latest `BitmapWorkerTask` working on each view.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting Tag to ImageView while starting image loading thread that why is set image to current one show at screen when thread completes it job .
you should pass some id as a parameter in **BitmapWorkerTask** class .